# Ubuntu one app: how can I sync a text file edited on my android device with ubuntu one?

Tags: sync, files, cloud, ubuntu-one

I've just got ubuntu one app on my android device to sync file between my android device and my desktop computer. I see that the app has the ability to automatically sync uploaded photos, can it also sync other files?

If I download a text file from my ubuntu one with this app and edit it on my android, how do I sync that file? I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I use an app called Foldersync in conjunction with Cryptonite. The former can synchronize any directory on your sdcard with a number of cloud providers. The latter handles encryption. You would use Encfs on the desktop to run the encryption there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an App for Android that supports the Ubuntu One Cloud, then try

> [**ES File Explorer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)

It can be found in the Google Play Store for Free.

It's a file manager but has Cloud features as well.
Instead of having a different App for each Cloud Service you use (Dropbox, Ubunutu One, SkyDrive, Google Drive, etc.. this rolls em all into one and it supports a decent number of Clouds.
Hope that is what you were looking for.

[image: CloudServs_ScreenS]
!

Answer (score 0):

It works similar to DropBox.  You put a new text file into your Ubuntu One folder on your PC, you check the app in your phone, and that same file will be there waiting for you.  It works both ways.

Comment: It does *NOT* work both ways. The app doesn't support syncing.

Comment: I just added a folder through the app and went to the website and it was there waiting for me.  I believe that is syncing?

Comment: Syncing would be if you add a file to your one folder on the sdcard and it would show up on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

i am using aerosync it works well and it's free and unlimited storage on any number of device but no cloud storage , it's having client for all platform . but you can sync a folder i do'nt know whether it can sync the internal changes in a file or that file with the newly edited version

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is doing the trick for me! Now I can edit the same file both in Vim on PC and in "DB Text Editor" on my Android phone. All synced in second in both directions.

1. Instal DB both on your Ubuntu and Android.
2. Make link to any folder inside Ubuntu One folder on PC (say "My texts") and move such link into your Dropbox folder on PC.
3. Put some file to "My texts" and try to edit on both devices.